# How to remove nan key from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have dictionary which has {'A':1, 'B':2, nan:3, 'C':4}. Is there are any way to remove this nan key value pair from the dictionary. This nan is float data type and rest of the keys are string.

Comment: how are you getting this dict?

Comment: This is simple:`del d[np.nan]`

Comment: @mind-protector not that simple...

Comment: @mind-protector, your answer works well for me. Don't forget the `import numpy as np` statement first.

Answer (score 5):

Use `NaN != NaN` and filter keys in dict comprehension:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k == k}
```

If need remove `Nones` and `NaNs` use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html):

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if pd.notna(k)}

print (d)
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

Comment: while this will work, I think it is more clear to use `{k: v for k,v in di.items() if not math.isnan(k)}` in the sense it is self-documenting, the `k == k` approach would probably require a comment